# TextView showing very small in the screen

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-tablelayout

In my app I have the following layout, and no matter what value I give the textview doesn't change its width. Can someone please help me in correcting this layout.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fill_rece"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_rec_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:src="@drawable/ipad_postcare_landscape_from" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I also get a warning near TableRow saying "This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is useless". Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try "fill_parent" for the "layout_width" attribute of TextView?

Comment: @user1406716 `fill_parent` is deprecated, using `match_parent` is correct.

Comment: remove `android:ems="10"`

Comment: The warning about useless is because you only have 1 `TableRow` inside `TableLayout`. Add more `TableRow` and the warning will be gone. Or just use other layout (e.g. `RelativeLayout`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one Insted of table use Linear Layout with and set `LAYOUT_WEIGHT` property. This property shares the equal amount of space for text view and image button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rec_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/fill_rece"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_rec_delete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/ipad_postcare_landscape_from" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried it. No change in the width.

Comment: @user2688158 are you removed your table layout or not....just replace this code in your XML.

Comment: Yes it is the same.. just have android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" and android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the LinearLayout

Answer (score 2):

try this....,you can add android:textSize="some value" which you want t o give

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="hllo"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use

```
android:layout_weight
```

I am mentioning one example for your help, also make sure your every element has height and weight with it, to display everything correctly

```
<LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
android:weightSum="1.0"
android:id="@+id/r1c1r2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:id="@+id/key"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:id="@+id/key2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the textsize using:

```
android:textSize="some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to give size according to your requirement you have the width of the table row and textview set as match_parent hence it(textview) can't change it's size.

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
```

Comment: I have tried with all possible values..doesn't change the width

Comment: I think the problem is in your line android:background="@drawable/fill_rece".You must defining the width size in the xml file.Try to remove the drawable file and change the width..it works!

Comment: Yeah that could be possible I'll try with getting a better drawable and see if it makes any difference. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have upvoted it for now..I will try with new drawable and then accept as the answer if it works fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: what are u displaying in the in the background of textview..just curious

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48039/discussion-between-user2688158-and-goonerdroid)